# How to send argument to class in Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, arguments, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I'm using Quartz.Net (version 2) for running a method in a class every day at 8:00 and 20:00 (IntervalInHours = 12)

Everything is OK since I used the same job and triggers as the tutorials on Quartz.Net, but I need to pass some arguments in the class and run the method bases on those arguments.

Can any one help me how I can use arguments while using Quartz.Net?

Answer (score 45):

You can use **JobDataMap**

```
jobDetail.JobDataMap["jobSays"] = "Hello World!";
jobDetail.JobDataMap["myFloatValue"] =  3.141f;
jobDetail.JobDataMap["myStateData"] = new ArrayList(); 

public class DumbJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        string instName = context.JobDetail.Name;
        string instGroup = context.JobDetail.Group;

        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

        string jobSays = dataMap.GetString("jobSays");
        float myFloatValue = dataMap.GetFloat("myFloatValue");
        ArrayList state = (ArrayList) dataMap["myStateData"];
        state.Add(DateTime.UtcNow);

        Console.WriteLine("Instance {0} of DumbJob says: {1}", instName, jobSays);
    }
}
```

Comment: JobDataMap link is broken

Comment: Actually quartz.net move or remove official documentation, removed link, I think it can exist without link as well

Answer (score 13):

To expand on @ArsenMkrt's answer, if you're doing the [2.x-style fluent job config](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/migration_guide.html), you could load up the `JobDataMap` like this:

```
var job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job name")
    .UsingJobData("x", x)
    .UsingJobData("y", y)
    .Build();
```

Comment: Except `UsingJobData()` only has overloads for a handful of value types

Comment: @DavidClarke See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543178/418950) where it notes that you can use the job instance to do something like `job.JobDataMap["logger"] = Logger;`

Answer (score 1):

### Abstract

Let me to extend a bit @arsen-mkrtchyan post with significant note which might avoid a painful support Quartz code in production:

### Problem (for persistance JobStore)

**Please remember about JobDataMap versioning** in case you're using persistent JobStore, e.g. AdoJobStore.

### Summary (TL;DR)

- Carefully think on constructing/editing your JobData otherwise it will lead to issues on triggering future jobs.
- Enable “quartz.jobStore.useProperties” config parameter as [official documentation recommends](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html) to minimize versioning problems. Use *JobDataMap.PutAsString()* later.

### Details

It's also stated in the documentation, however, not so highlighted, but might lead to big maintenance problem if e.g. you removing some parameter in the next version of you app:

> If you use a persistent JobStore (discussed in the JobStore section of this tutorial) you should use some care in deciding what you place in the JobDataMap, because the object in it will be serialized, and they therefore become prone to class-versioning problems.

Also there is related note about configuring JobStore mentioned in the [relevant document](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html):

> The “quartz.jobStore.useProperties” config parameter can be set to “true” (defaults to false) in order to instruct AdoJobStore that all values in JobDataMaps will be strings, and therefore can be stored as name-value pairs, rather than storing more complex objects in their serialized form in the BLOB column. This is much safer in the long term, as you avoid the class versioning issues that there are with serializing your non-String classes into a BLOB.