# Use DI with quartz

Tags: c#, quartz.net

This is my code and it is not working, because apparently, `IJobDetails` needs to be created with job builder. Is there any way to create Job with external dependencies given in constructor?

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<BbProcessor, BbProcessor>();
IJobDetail jobProcessor = container.Resolve<BbProcessor>() as IJobDetail;

// construct a scheduler factory
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(jobProcessor , trigger);
```

The cast is bad, but this is just example what I'm trying to do (`BbProcessor` is the class with dependencies given to constructor and doing work I want to do).

```
public class BbProcessor : IJob
{ 
    private readonly Repository _repository;
    public BbProcessor(Repository Repository) 
    { 
        _repository = Repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code to BbProcessor?

Comment: `public class BbProcessor : IJob
    {
        private readonly Repository _repository;

        public BbProcessor(Repository Repository)
        {
            _repository = Repository;
        }`

Comment: I think you also need a no-arg constructor. See my edited answer below.

Comment: So we both figured this out in same time, I have idea already, tomorrow will update it with solution

Comment: Check out this project that integrates Quartz with Unity: https://github.com/hbiarge/Quartz.Unity

Answer (score 1):

BbProcessor implements IJob not IJobDetail which is why the cast fails. You could register the BbProcessor class with Unity using the interface instead ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#registertype_mapping)) but thats not what you really want:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IJob, BbProcessor>();
IJob jobProcessor = container.Resolve<IJob>();
```

In fact, BbProcessor must have a no-arg constructor. [See Documentation.](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/4fc0f1b6-401d-a7aa-224c-c2fd34cec94e.htm)
Also, [look here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html) for a complete example on setting up your job.

You create an IJobDetail like this:

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<BbProcessor>().WithIdentity("Job BB","Group BB").Build();
```

JobBuilder does not use your resolved type. See if this project where unity is integrated with quartz gets you what you're after: https://github.com/hbiarge/Quartz.Unity

Comment: Looks like I need to create job like this: `IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<BbProcessor>()
                    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                    .Build();` but still, it uses empty constructr (at least looks like it) and I need to work around this

Answer (score 0):

This post gave me answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13857396/4350808 (I'm passing same instance to created jobs with JobDataMap)